# Index is out of bounds when using .pivot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a dataframe with size (2481430, 2) and I want to group by columns B with no summarization for column codex.

I used .pivot and it returned 'index 2025068794 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2024681638'

```
   codex    B
0  D0003    20
1  D0004    21
2  D0003    21
3  D0001    20
4  D0002    20
5  D0005    20


df.pivot(columns = 'B', values = 'codex')
```

This the expected result

```
   20       21
0  D0003    D0004
1  D0001    D0003
2  D0002    NaN
3  D0005    NaN
```

Comment: your code works fine with the given data

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, Actually, this won't work because indices are not normalized.

Comment: Is performance important?

Comment: yes, my dataframe is just a sample

Comment: @DiogoPedroso - so it depends of data, so best test both solutions bellow.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html)

You can use `groupby`, then concatenate `pd.Series` objects with normalized indices:

```
grouper = df.groupby('B')['codex']
res = pd.concat((pd.Series(vals.values, name=b) for b, vals in grouper), axis=1)

print(res)

      20     21
0  D0003  D0004
1  D0001  D0003
2  D0002    NaN
3  D0005    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new indices:

```
df = pd.pivot(columns = df['B'], values = df['codex'], index= df.groupby('B').cumcount())
print (df)
B     20     21
0  D0003  D0004
1  D0001  D0003
2  D0002    NaN
3  D0005    NaN
```